# WPF access to a resource from c# code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my XAML:

```xml
   <TabControl Name="me" SelectionChanged="me_SelectionChanged">

        <TabControl.Resources>

            <Storyboard x:Name="fadein" x:Key="fatal">

                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="fade" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:3">

                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem Header="MyTabItem">
            <Grid Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0.7"></Grid>


        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
```

I'm trying to access the `fatal` animation through the C# code but I can't...

```
    public void me_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (sender == null)
            return;

        fatal.Stop();// cant recognize `fatal`
    }
```

C# can't identify what `fatal` is.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can do the following:

```
StoryBoard sb = (StoryBoard)me.FindResource("fatal");
```

or

```
StoryBoard sb = (StoryBoard)me.Resources["fatal"];
```

Comment: allright tnx. do you know how to trigger the animation? i just got a little bit confused. i would really appreciate if you could help in this too @ckruczek